# how to save rowId from insert again into sqlite

Tags: flutter, sqlite

sorry if I didnt clarify clearly,
now I have some data saving into sqlite, like followings:

```
Future insertTarget({Profile profile}) async {
    try {
      if (profile != null) {
        Database db = await getDataBase();

        String profileName = profile.profileName;
        String profilePortraitUrl = profile.profilePortraitUrl;
        String profileMemorialSpeech = profile.profileMemorialSpeech;
        String profileBirthDay =
            formatTime(formatter: formatter_1, time: profile.profileBirthDay);
        String profileDeathDay =
            formatTime(formatter: formatter_1, time: profile.profileDeathDay);
        String profileCreatedTime = formatTime(
            formatter: formatter_1, time: profile.profileCreatedTime);

        return await db.transaction((txn) async {
          int rowid = await txn.rawInsert(
              'INSERT INTO $tablename($columnProfileName, $columnProfilePortraitUrl, $columnProfileMemorialSpeech, $columnProfileBirthDay, $columnProfileDeathDay, $columnProfileCreatedTime) VALUES("$profileName", "$profilePortraitUrl", "$profileMemorialSpeech", "$profileBirthDay", "$profileDeathDay", "$profileCreatedTime")');
          return {'rowid': rowid};
        });
      } else {
        print('$profile is null');
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('error$e');
    }
  }
```

so in the end I got the rowid from methode `insertTarget`, and when I insert the profile:

```
  homeProfileProvider.insertTarget(profile: newProfile).then((value){
                newProfile.profileId = value['rowid'];
              });
```

I can set profileId the value of rowid, here is my question, how to save this profileId now? Should I insert into sqlite again? and how? thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Why do u want to save the profileid (which essentially is rowid) into the database again?

Comment: hi Hassan, I tried to print profileId after reboot app, and returned null, it seems although rowid is created and saved in sqlite, but profileId is set still with null value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return row id then use return type of Future<Map<String,dynamic>> in method